# Setting empty view for android ListView not working for views created in Java

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

I have no problem setting the empty view for a ListView if the emptyView is inflated from xml. But if I create the view on the fly, it does not appear. So what’s wrong with the following code?

```
if (myData.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(“there is no data“);
            TextView emptyView = new TextView(this);
            emptyView.setText("no data found");
            myListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
        }
```

Comment: you do not need the `myData.isEmpty()` check. EmptyView only shows if the list is empty. Be sure to use listVIew.setEmptyView() before using listView.setAdapter()

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add the empty view to the parrent before setting it as the empty view.

```
    if (myData.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(“there is no data“);
        TextView emptyView = new TextView(this);
        emptyView.setText("no data found");
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myListView.getParent();
        parent.addView(emptyView);
        myListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But that's not exactly the solution I am looking for. By setting the view to the parent, I in fact don't even need to subsequently pass it to myListView for it to show. But then if next time around the list is **NOT** empty, the empty string is still visible. That's certainly not what I want. To help you, just imagine  I am using an EditText view to search for data on a server and the listView is to dynamically show the result. So I am not leaving and returning to the activity: I stay put.